# How GA count page views?

Tags: google-analytics-api, episerver

I'm have a issue about view numbers correspond between Episerver A/B testing and Google Analytics. That have a big different in number so I want to ask how GA working in views count to find the reason.

Episerver A/B testing views count work like this:

> If they ARE a participant we programmatically determine if they are to get the original content or a variant.  That gets saved in their cookie.
>   When they actually view the page we then mark it as a view.
>   If they visit the page again we check if they viewed it and if so ignore it - so we do not increment the view.
>   So, one user will only count as one view, no matter how many times they visit a page.

Answer (score 0):

GA count every page view, so it's natural that GA and Episerver A/B gets different results.

From the GA pages:

> Pageview A pageview (or pageview hit, page tracking hit) is an
>   instance of a page being loaded (or reloaded) in a browser. Pageviews
>   is a metric defined as the total number of pages viewed.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6086080?hl=en